# В мобильной версии не работают кнопки голосования и "Добавить комментарий"

Tags: дефект, мобильная-версия

С недавних пор не работают вышеуказанные кнопки. Это ссылки с "#" в конце адреса. Видимо, обработчик не добавляется

[image: голоса] [image: добавить комментарий]

Проверял на хроме и Habit Browser

Comment: Мобильная версия - это имеется в виду сайт, открытый в мобильном браузере или же приложение Stack Exchange? Только что проверил в обоих вариантах все работает.

Comment: Добавьте картинок, потому что непонятно, о чем речь. У меня голосование и добавление комментариев работает в мобильной версии сайта. Как раз этот комментарий так написал.

Comment: @Yaant  открытый в мобильном браузере

Comment: @αλεχολυτ добавил

Comment: У меня всё работает. Проверял в Chrome на Android и iOS. Может у вас какие аддоны установлены? Заодно проверьте в приватном режиме.